# What are the insights about invariant measures in PDE’s?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

anyone can be, please, give me exemples where the [invariant measures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_measure#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20invariant%20measure,is%20invariant%20under%20shear%20mapping.) are useful in partial differential equations?
Actually, i work with elliptic and parabolic PDE’s, the first one are fully nonlinear equations while the second class is of the p-laplacian type.

In short, what are the insights for a people who study PDE’s about concept of invariant measures in Ergodic Theory?